# Google scripts web app permissions for specific service out of organization

Tags: google-apps-script, server, web-applications, permissions

I am using google app scripts deployed as web app to transfer sensors information from an Arduino that puts out an http request, to a server(https://www.pushingbox.com/), and on to app scripts.
Until now, my web app was published to anyone with the link and now I can only do that to someone inside the organization. I would like to approve only pushingbox.com to be able to use GET as I did before.
Is there a simple way of doing so?
Thanks

Comment: Have you googled using Arduino with google apps script

Comment: Yes, the whole process works with permissions to everyone, my problem is granting specific permissions to just the server(pushingbox website)